# Programmatically wrap ETH by interacting with Wrapped Ether contract in Web3.py

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, wrapped-tokens

Looking at the contract for [Wrapped Ether](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code#L43), I noticed that it uses a function called `deposit` to wrap ETH.

The function `deposit` itself does not get an argument. However, at the top of the script, I noticed `event  Deposit(address indexed dst, uint wad);`

I suppose I have to create this event with the proper arguments (wallet address and how much to be wrapped). I am not sure how to create this event when, I think, I can only interact with functions within the contract.

I am trying to do this in web3.py.  I was able to successfully unwrap an existing wETH by calling the `withdraw` function in the [wETH contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code).

Comment: If you want to use a more secure Wrapped Ether contract, I created this one a few weeks ago: https://etherscan.io/address/0x6be7ef70b35fdb9042d704c920d003b414385c76 With the original WETH you can lock your funds, be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to call the deposit() function of the WETH contract and define the number of ETH to be wrapped to WETH in the transaction's `value` key.

Example of working, unsigned tx:

```
tx = weth_contract.functions.deposit().buildTransaction({
        'chainId': 1,
        'gas': 100000,
        'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
        'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(use_this_address),
        'value': w3.toWei(1.0, "ether")
    })
```

As an alternative, you can just send ethers to the smart contract's address, as a normal transfer between two accounts. The contract has a fallback function `function() public payable` that will take care of all the logic because it  actually calls `deposit()`.

Comment: how about unwrapping (withdraw) please? I seem to have an issue ...